# One-to-one + Continuity implies strictly monotonic

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, functions, continuity

I came across to a theorem on the book Elementary Real Analysis by Kenneth Ross. Theorem states:

**Let f be a one-to-one continuous function on an interval I. Then
f is strictly increasing  or strictly
decreasing.**
My question is why do we need continuity. If the function is one-to-one then doesn't it necessarily mean that it must be strictly monotonic. I think I am missing something in my logic. Probably, the one-to-one doesn't necessarily maintain the order required for monotonicity. Somebody, please clarify this.

Comment: $f(x)=x$ when $x\in\mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=-x$ when $x\notin\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Look at piecewise functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a question like this, *start drawing pictures*.  In your case, you want to draw pictures of one-to-one but discontinuous functions.  Can you draw one that is not monotone?  Sure:  try something like $f: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} -x, & -1 \leq x \leq 0 \\ x+2, & 0 <x \leq 1.  \end{cases}
$$
This is one-to-one on the domain interval but neither increasing nor decreasing.  It is, of course, discontinuous.

[image]